# parse object to json or dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a string

```
Type: xxxx  ECID: 0x0099999 UDID: 3204e63234567dfd7ad Location: 0x22100000 Name: AAAAA
```

in addition, Name field could contain white space e.g. "Jack's apple" etc

and there are multiple copies of this kind strings too.

how could I parse this to json or dictionary in python?

many thanks

Comment: What delineates keys and values?  Are values guaranteed not to contain whitespace?  (I'm assuming there are no other keys to worry about, like `"Last Seen:"`.) Also, are values guaranteed to never end with a colon?

Comment: actually values for name could contain space

Comment: "actually values for name could contain space" --- That's a _really important_ part of the problem, and I believe it invalidates both of the answers already posted.

Comment: If you [edit] that into your question, you should also comment on both answers to let their authors know your question has changed.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing a string like this is simple with some straight-forward [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
import re
import json
regex = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>[^:]+):  # match any non-colon characters and store as 'key'
                       \s+              # followed by one or more whitespace characters
                       (?P<value>\S+)   # match any non-whitespace characters and store as 'value'
                       \s+""",          # and gobble up the rest of the whitespace
                   re.VERBOSE)          # (allow comments in regular expressions)

result = {match.group('key'): match.group('value') for match in regex.finditer(input_string)}
json.dumps(result)
```

**Edit**: If the values contain optional whitespace, regular expressions can handle that, too!  Just use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
import re
import json

input_string = "Type: xx xx  ECID: 0x00999 99 UDID: 3204e632 34567 dfd7ad Location: 0x2 210 00 00 Name: AA AA A"  # lots of whitespace!

regex = re.compile(r"""(?P<key>\S+):     # match any non-whitespace characters followed by a colon and store as 'key'
                       \s*               # followed by optional whitespace characters
                       (?P<value>.*?)    # match any characters and store as 'value'...
                       \s*               # gobble up any extra whitespace
                       (?=$|\S+:)""",    # until either the end of a line or a new key is found
                   re.VERBOSE)           # (allow comments in regular expressions)

result = {match.group('key'): match.group('value') for match in regex.finditer(input_string)}
json.dumps(result)
```

Output:

```
'{"UDID": "3204e632 34567 dfd7ad", "ECID": "0x00999 99", "Name": "AA AA A", "Location": "0x2 210 00 00", "Type": "xx xx"}'
```

This assumes that the keys do not contain whitespace.  If both keys and values can contain whitespace, then there has to be some other way to distinguish them than your example suggests, because it would be impossible to know where a value ends and a key begins.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Type: xxxx  ECID: 0x0099999 UDID: 3204e63234567dfd7ad Location: 0x22100000 Name: AAAAA"
l = s.split()
d = {l[i][:-1]: l[i+1] for i in range(0, len(l) - 1, 2)}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the values will never contain whitespace?